# npm audit report manual review confusing point

Tags: npm, audit

In my angular project, I run `npm audit` to check the security weakness, based on the doc, I can understand most of the report. 
But not fully understand the `manual review` part, the related report is as following:

```
# Run  npm install jquery@3.4.1  to resolve 2 vulnerabilities
SEMVER WARNING: Recommended action is a potentially breaking change

  Moderate        Prototype Pollution                                           

  Package         jquery                                                        

  Dependency of   jquery                                                        

  Path            jquery                                                        

  More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/796                        




  High            Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)                                    

  Package         jquery                                                        

  Dependency of   jquery                                                        

  Path            jquery                                                        

  More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/328 

                                 Manual Review                                  
             Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve             

          Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance           


  Moderate        Prototype Pollution

  Package         jquery

  Patched in      >=3.4.0

  Dependency of   ms-signalr-client

  Path            ms-signalr-client > jquery

  More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/796


  High            Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)

  Package         jquery

  Patched in      >=3.0.0

  Dependency of   ms-signalr-client

  Path            ms-signalr-client > jquery

  More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/328
```

so my understanding is: `jquery` has some security issue, and `jquery` is the dependency of `ms-signalr-client`. And I also checked that `ms-signalr-client` is used in `dependency`, not `devDependency` in package.json. So I need to fix it, since it influences  the production code. Right?

So the `SEMVER WARNING` means that if I upgrade the `jquery` to 3.4.1, then the  `ms-signalr-client` can break. Right?

And what I can do? Next step is making the `ms-signalr-client` support the upgraded `jquery`, right?

So what's the best practice for this? My current plan is skipping it for now. Thank you.